# useSession's update method not updating the session - NextAuth

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js13

I have added an active property to my next auth jwt tokken and session. The active property exists on user object which lives on database. Upon email confirmation, I update the active property to be true then I run update() method returned by useSession() to update the session.

This is the official way of updating the session in NextAuth : https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#updating-the-session

The problem is my session object still contains old active value which is false.

It only updates if I log out and login again. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Here is my code which calls update method.

```js
    verifyToken(token as string)
      .then(() => {
        if (session && session.status === "authenticated") {
          session.update();
          console.log("Update the session");
        }
      })
```